# Wild card matching

Tags: regex, perl

I need to match a sentences which contains both wild card character \ and . in same sentence.How to do it with Perl?

Say suppose my file has following sentences :

```
ttterfasghti.
ddseghies/affag
hhail/afgsh.
asfsdgagh/
adterhjc/sgsagh.
```

My expected output should be :

```
hhail/afgsh.
adterhjc/sgsagh.
```

Comment: @BookOfZeus that question does not apply, because it talks about string variables, not regexes.

Comment: Finally I get it, the formatting in your question was incorrect. You are talking about multiple lines. I'll improve my answer.

Comment: Can the two characters appear in any order, or only a / followed by a period?

Comment: @Shawn Any order but the matching line should contain both / and .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a clarification from a comment

> Any order but the matching line should contain both `/` and `.`

an easy way

```
perl -wne'print if m{/} and m{\.}' filename
```

This is inefficient in the sense that it starts the regex engine twice and scans each string twice.  However, in most cases that is unnoticable while this code is much clearer than a single regex for the task.

I use `{}` delimiters so to not have to escape the `/`, in which case the `m` in front is compulsory. Then I use the same `m{...}` on the other pattern for consistency.

---

A most welcome inquiry comes that this be done in a script, not one-liner!  Happy to oblige.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = shift || die "Usage: $0 file\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    print if m{/} and m{\.};
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: It is working but I need your code in the form of script or program but not like command line.

Comment: @cherry  Edited, and will edit some more.  Let me know if any particular explanations/comments would be helpful.

Comment: Awesome!Thank you!Can you able to do anything with this program   
open(a,"<file.txt");
while(my $line = <a>) {
if($line =~ m/\w+/\w*\.//){
 print $line;

 }
}
close(a);

Comment: Please indent it in proper format for my code and analyze it.

Comment: @cherry  The code you show has two problems: (1) It won't do what you ask for, because it will only match first `/` and then `.`.  It won't match lines on which there is a `.` and after it the `/` (and no more `.`). (2) Don't use `a` for a filehandle -- it may actually work but just wait for trouble.  Instead, make it a "lexical" variable, like `$fh`

Comment: Okay!Thanks for sharing info friend :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188330/discussion-between-cherry-and-zdim).

Answer (score 3):

This feels like a duplicate, but I just can't find a good previous question for this.

For `/` there are two ways:

- use `m//` operator with different separator characters, e.g. `m,<regex with />,`, `m{<regex with />}`, or
- escape it, i.e. `/\//`

For `.` use escaping.

Note that inside a character class (`[...]`) many special characters no longer need escaping.

Hence we get:

```perl
$ perl <dummy.txt -ne 'print "$1: $_" if m,(\w+/\w*\.),'
hhail/afgsh.: hhail/afgsh.
adterhjc/sgsagh.: adterhjc/sgsagh.
```

i.e. the line is printed if it contains one-or-more word characters, followed by a `/`, zero-or-more word characters, ending with a `.`.

Recommended reading [perlrequick](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) & [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

---

**UPDATE** after OP clarified the requirement in a comment:

```perl
 $ perl <dummy.txt -ne 'print if m,/, && m{\.}'
 hhail/afgsh.
 adterhjc/sgsagh.
```

Comment: Note clarification from a comment: "_**Any order** but the matching line should contain both `/` and `.`_"  (my emphasis)

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the latest comments from OP. Thanks.