# Strange regular expression

Tags: perl

This regular expression will match exactly one `/`  and one `.` in a line. But why is it matching? Can anyone explain to me each characters role in this regular expression clearly?

```perl
if ($fp =~ m{^[^/]*/[^/]*$} and $fp =~ m{^[^.]*.[^.]$})
{
    print $fp;
}
```

Comment: The 2nd regex does not match your description, i.e. it is broken and will mismatch.

Comment: @StefanBecker Indeed, and I must take the blame: I offered that line, with that blooper (was meant to be literal period, `\.`), in a [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188330/discussion-between-cherry-and-zdim) following [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54664459/4653379).  It also needs a quantifier on the last character class ...

Comment: @zdim I am not clear about that expression that's why i have asked that question for the suggestion.Is that anything hurt you,friend?

Comment: Hum?  No, no hurt -- good that you asked about something that wasn't clear! I am glad to see that!  (I don't think that the question should've been closed.)  I was just confirming the observation about missing bits (`.` instead of `\.`, and then the quantifier `*`).  It's all good.

Comment: Btw, when you want one of each (`.` and `/`), there's a simpler way using transliteration operator (look it up [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)):  `if (1 == $v =~ tr{.}{} and 1 == $v =~ tr{/}{})`. It changes the character (literal characters only, no variables, escapes or such) and returns the number of times it did this in the string.  Counts it, in other words, and you can tests that it's exactly 1.

Answer (score 11):

```
if($fp =~ m{^[^/]*/[^/]*$} and $fp =~ m{^[^.]*.[^.]$}) {
            ^\ / ^^\ / ^^
            | |  || |  ||
------------- |  || |  ||
begin line    |  || |  ||
---------------  || |  ||
any char but /   || |  ||
------------------| |  ||
zero or more      | |  ||
------------------  |  ||
one /               |  ||
---------------------  ||
any char but /         ||
------------------------|
zero or more            |
------------------------|
end of line
```

So it search

- begin or line (^),
- followed by zero or more occurrence (*) of any char but / ([^/])
- followed by a /
- followed by zero or more occurrence (*) of any char but / ([^/])
- followed by end of line ($)

The "." search is similar and the 'if' triggers if both are true.

Note that `[...]` searches a char in a range. For instance `[abc]` searches either a 'a', a 'b', or a 'c'. If first char is '^' test is reversed and `[^/]` is any char, but '/'.

Comment: Note the observation that in the second regex the `.` should be `\.` and the character class should have a `*`.  Not the point of the answer but perhaps add a note for completeness?

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answers are correct in explaining the regex, they do fail to point out that the 2nd regex is actually broken. As written it will match

- start of line
- followed by zero-or-more non-`.` (dot) characters
- followed by *ANY* character, except `\n`
- followed by *ONE* non-`.` (dot) character
- end of line

Proof:

```
$ echo "This should NOT match" | perl -ne 'print if m{^[^.]*.[^.]$}'
This should NOT match          <--- INCORRECT MATCH
$ echo "This should. match"    | perl -ne 'print if m{^[^.]*.[^.]$}'
                               <--- INCORRECT MIS-MATCH
$ echo "This should match.!"   | perl -ne 'print if m{^[^.]*.[^.]$}'
This should match.!            <-- CORRECT (by luck)
$ echo "This should match."    | perl -ne 'print if m{^[^.]*.[^.]$}'
This should match.             <-- CORRECT
```

Correct would be

- the `.` needs to be escaped (`\.`)
- the 2nd character class needs a `*`

```
$ echo "This should NOT match" | perl -ne 'print if m{^[^.]*\.[^.]*$}'
                               <-- CORRECT
$ echo "This should. match"    | perl -ne 'print if m{^[^.]*\.[^.]*$}'
This should. match             <-- CORRECT
$ echo "This should match.!"   | perl -ne 'print if m{^[^.]*\.[^.]*$}'
This should match.!            <-- CORRECT
$ echo "This should match."    | perl -ne 'print if m{^[^.]*\.[^.]*$}'
This should match.             <-- CORRECT
```

Answer (score 1):

The first expresion: m matches { opens expresion ^ first of line, [^/]* any character not '/' 0 or more times, '/' literal '/', again [^/]*, $ end of line, } closes the expresion.